# PHP isset is returning false on non-empty variable

Tags: php, laravel, isset

I have a situation here where I have to use `isset()` and it is returning `false` even when the variable has value in it. My `PHP` version is this:

```
PHP 7.0.33-14+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:55:39) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-14+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

My `laravel` version is this:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.5.28",
```

Here is a piece of code with `isset()` in it:

```
return isset($this->pivot->factor) ? $this->pivot->factor : $this->getFactor();
```

Now if I do this:

```
\Log::debug('$this->pivot->factor', [$this->pivot->factor]);
```

the value in the variable `$this->pivot->factor` is `11` which is correct but If I do `dd(isset($this->pivot->factor));` , it return `false`. what is going on here? How to fix this?

**EDIT**
This is the method:

```
 public function getLinkedFactor()
    {
        if ($this->priceResponce) {

            $rateAdditionals = $this->priceResponce->rate->additionals;

            $rateAdditional = $rateAdditionals->filter(function ($item) {
                return $item->id == $this->id;
            })->first();


            if ($rateAdditional && $rateAdditional->pivot->factor) {
                return $rateAdditional->pivot->factor;
            }
        }

        \Log::debug('$this->pivot->factor', [$this->pivot->factor]);

        return isset($this->pivot->factor) ? $this->pivot->factor : $this->getFactor();
    }
```

And this is the test accessing that code:

```
/**
     * @test
     */
    public function shouldConsiderLinkedFactor()
    {
        $officeAttrs = [
            'id' => 1,
            'additional_id' => 2,
            'office_id' => 3,
            'factor' => 11
        ];

        $officeAdditional = $this->makeEloquentMock(OfficeAdditional::class, $officeAttrs);
        $officeAdditional->shouldReceive('hasGetMutator')->andReturn(true);
        $officeAdditional->shouldReceive('getAttributeValue')->andReturn($officeAttrs['factor']);
        $officeAdditional->shouldReceive('toJson');

        $attributes = [
            'additional_type_id' => 2,
            'factor'   => 10,
            'name'     => 'test fixed additional',
            'description' => 'asdasdasd',
            'has_input' => false,
            'kind'     => 'linked',
            'input_label' => '',
            'carrier_facing_cost' => 1,
            'min' => 5,
            'max' => 10
        ];

        $additional = Additional::make($attributes);


        $additional->pivot = $officeAdditional;

        $this->assertEquals($officeAttrs['factor'], $additional->getLinkedFactor());
    }
```

Comment: Show us the context of the code, there's too little information here to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Are you executing both codes at the exact same position? Please show us the full code.

Comment: What is `pivot`? What is `factor`? Don't just return it - add the proper debug statements in front and after reading the value.

Comment: where are you running this code, inside a model?

Comment: @Jerodev Have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @lagbox yes it is in Model.

Comment: This happens when a class defines magic getters and fails to implement `__isset`. [Example](https://3v4l.org/ZM8nI).

Comment: @Jeto what could be the possible solution here?

Comment: @Saani What is `Additional`? Is it a custom class? I mean it's still hard to see which class that `pivot` property is of.

Comment: @Jeto Additional is model class. If you can see the test code there is a line: `$additional->pivot = $officeAdditional;` So pivot is Additional class property.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around in my situation which is like this. I replaced this line:

```
return isset($this->pivot->factor) ? $this->pivot->factor : $this->getFactor();
```

with this:

```
return $this->pivot === null ? $this->getFactor() : $this->pivot->factor === null ? $this->getFactor() : $this->pivot->factor;
```

This way I don't have to use `isset()`.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have 50 points to join in the comments above, so I hope this is enough of an answer. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships

update: replace last line of getLinkedFactor with

```
return 
    $this->whenPivotLoaded('pivot_table_name', function () {
            return $this->pivot->factor;
        }) 
    ?? 
    $this->getFactor();
```

Comment: can you explain how that fits into my situation?

Comment: @Saani are you using a resource? as per your comments above it seems you are using a model, not a resource, correct?

Comment: @lagbox yes! I am using Model.

Comment: @Saani then unfortunately this particular answer does not apply